# Размер списка в Python и объём оперативной памяти

Tags: python, python-internals

При исполнении следующего кода

```
n = 10 ** 9
alist = [0] * n
```

Компьютер начинает работать очень медленно (похоже из-за нехватки оперативной памяти?). Если я правильно понял, в этом случае список создаётся и вмещается в память, но занимает такое её количество, что всё начинает "тормозить". При этом, например, если размер списка равен `10 ** 10`, то сразу выдаётся `MemoryError`. Получается, что пайтон не может вместить список такого размера в оперативную память (её физически не хватает) или стоят какие-то ограничения на размер списка?

Хотелось бы разобраться, почему так происходит в этих двух случаях. Также хотел узнать, как лучше защититься от зависаний вследствие нехватки оперативной памяти (каждый раз заранее прикидывать, какой объём памяти будет занимать список,  написать какой-нибудь код, где будет проверяться это дело или ещё как-то?).

**Обновление**

Списки такого размера мне понадобились при нахождении всех простых чисел меньше `n` с помощью решета Эратосфена. Я начал с `n = 100` и постепенно увеличивал размер списка. Вплоть до  `10 ** 8` всё работало, а потом начались неприятные тормоза. Соответственно, хотел узнать как можно защититься (от себя) в таких случаях. Может есть какие-нибудь рекомендации по максимальному размеру списка в процентах от объёма оперативной памяти, чтобы не возникало таких зависаний?

Comment: Совершенно верно, на лицо явная нехватка памяти. Даже если не брать во внимание дополнительные расходы на формирование списка и тупо посчитать кол-во элементов по 4 байта, то это 37.25 GB. Встречный вопрос, от кого вы пытаетесь защититься? От себя же? Для каких вообще задач может потребоваться держать такие объемы данных в памяти? При большой фантазии, придумать конечно же можно, но к чему?

Comment: Все просто, в первом случае, когда 10**9 элементов, они физически помещаются в установленную память, это примерно 3,72 Гб и python пытается их туда записать. Во втором случае они не могут поместиться в память чисто физически, поэтому сразу выдается ошибка MemoryError и python даже не пытается писать данные в память.

Comment: А непосредственно тормоза происходят из-за свопа.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86

Comment: @marcin63, измените подход к решению данной задачи. Обрабатывайте за раз списки меньшего размера накапливая отдельный список простых чисел. К примеру, обработать список 1-10000, оставшиеся простые числа поместить в prime_numbers, обработайте список 10001-20000 воспользовавшись списком prime_numbers и самим собой, оставшее опять в prime_numbers, и т.д. Так вам не придется создавать список гигантских размеров и сможете обработать значения большие чем 10 ** 10. Да, подход сложнее в реализации, медленее, чем на теоретической машине, но значительно быстрее на практике (ибо не будет свопов).

Comment: в тему: [How many bytes per element are there in a Python list (tuple)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/135664/4279)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[0] * n` список в CPython требует примерно `n * <размер указателя>`  байтов (можно посмотреть на реализации функций [`list_repeat()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5b4a8161fa89db09af0f185d4b78fadbf3aeb4f3/Objects/listobject.c#L509-L547), [`PyList_New(n)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5b4a8161fa89db09af0f185d4b78fadbf3aeb4f3/Objects/listobject.c#L129-L180), [`PyMem_Malloc()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5b4a8161fa89db09af0f185d4b78fadbf3aeb4f3/Objects/obmalloc.c#L319-L326), чтобы увидеть случаи когда `MemoryError` сразу выбрасывается без попытки выделения памяти -- на 32-битной платформе эти пределы достаточно низкие: `n = 536870911` (`((2**32 - 1) >> 1) // 4`), на 64-битной платформе маловероятно что эти условия сработают -- другими словами: вы можете создавать списки настолько большими насколько у вас памяти хватит -- *практически* ограничений нет.

Защита простая: узнайте сколько у вас на компьютере памяти и не пытайтесь  выделить больше этого кол-ва.

По конкретной задаче: можно уменьшить потребление памяти в 4-8 раз, если использовать `array`, `numpy.array` вместо списка. Можно ещё снизить, если предварительно исключить маленькие простые числа (wheel-optimizations), cм. [Fastest way to list all primes below N](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2068372/4279). Можно ещё `gmpy2` использовать (до 16 раз меньше памяти), см. [Speed up bitstring/bit operations in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2897297/4279)

Для `n` более `10**9` может иметь смысл [использовать решето Аткина, которое требует  N<sup>1/2+o(1)</sup> бит памяти, вместо решета Эратосфена O(N<sup>1/2</sup>(log log N)/log N))](https://stackoverflow.com/a/175956/4279).

Существуют [алгоритмы без верхней границы](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117119-sieve-of-eratosthenes/), если не известно заранее сколько простых чисел надо.

Если нужны бо́ льшие числа, то можно использовать алгоритмы, которые работают посегментно (позволяют как верхную так и нижнюю границу указать), например, [`pyprimesieve`](https://github.com/jaredks/pyprimesieve).

Answer (score 0):

для списка символов более точно размер списка указан в [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/741232/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-200mb-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-1gb-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82/741301#741301)
если коротко, то зависит еще и от разрядности машины.
Более того список требует на свое "поддержание" на каждые элемент больше памяти, чем сами хранимые данные. Для каждого элемента от 40 до 79 байта плюс к длине элемента.
Так что лучше использовать массивы array или numpy.

Comment: Интересно кто так настойчиво минусует почти все ваши ответы?

Comment: @MaxU ... О! Как говорят в добрых одесских анекдотах )

Answer (score -1):

Можно попробовать использовать другой алгоритма поиска простых чисел. К примеру http://python-dao.rpisarev.org.ua/2015/08/finding-prime-numbers-in-given-interval.html

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.