# Загрузка списка из 200MB файла отбирает больше 1GB памяти. Почему такой прирост?

Tags: python, память, список

Есть текстовый файл `list.txt`, состоящий из строк вида:

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
...
```

Файл на диске занимает 196 МБ.

При загрузке его следующим методом:

```
L = []
F = open('list.txt')
L = F.readlines()
F.close()
```

оперативная память, занимаемая процессом становится порядка 1,3 ГБ.

Помогите разобраться, почему такой прирост использования памяти относительно файла на диске?

Comment: А сколько строк в файле?

Comment: Более 16 млн. строк

Comment: Тогда средняя длина строки получится 12 байт, а издержки на ее хранение во внутренних структурах намного больше: [PyVarObject](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyVarObject).

Comment: При работе с большими файлами вообще лучше стараться не грузить их целиком в память. Если можно обрабатывать файл построчно (обработали строку - загрузили новую, старую не храним), то лучше так и делать.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
>>> sys.getsizeof('hello')
54
>>> sys.getsizeof('h')
50
>>> sys.getsizeof('hellohello')
59
>>>
```

Вот пример из windows10 64 битная. Видно, что одна строка занимает 49 байт + 1байт на символ. Но! это ж UTF-8 строки и для кириллицы пойдет больше символов.

```
sys.getsizeof('Вася')
82
>>>
```

по формуле: 74 байта + 2 на символ.
Теперь о затратах на хранение в списке. ЭТО на х64 винде:
40+8*количество_элементов байт.
Пробуем сложить, считая что каждое имя ровно 5 символов:

16кк * ( (74 + 2*5) + 8) + 40 = 1 472 кк то есть ваши 1.3 Гига

Что делать?
1) посмотрите массивы  `numpy` - они экономнее и по памяти и быстрее в работе. Думаю, массив `numpy` будет примерно 300кк памяти, так как он почти "фортрановский" :-)
2) Измените алгоритм так, чтобы не хранить в памяти весь список. Как правило это удается. Например чтение из файла используя `yield` генераторы и т.д.