# Какие структуры данных используют стандартные контейнеры python

Tags: python, python-3.x, структуры-данных

Где можно узнать о том какими структурами данных представлены контейнеры: **string, list, tuple, set, dict** или какую асимптотику обещает стандарт python для этих контейнеров?

Я думаю это довольно важно, если скрипт работает с большим объемом данных и знать какие операции дорогостоящие, а какие нет довольно полезно знать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот тут сложности https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity.

Какие именно структуры данных используются не оговаривается. Как вариант, посмотреть популярную C-реализацию https://github.com/python/cpython или ту, которую вы используете.

Answer (score 3):

Вот здесь по ссылке: [ЖМИ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/741232/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%B7-200mb-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-1gb-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82/741301#741301) - затраты памяти на стандартный список.
Для экономии памяти лучше использовать tuple, или если тип числовой - массив библиотеки ***[numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/)***.
Он (этот массив) - при указании хранить данные по столбцам - экономичный и совпадает со старым добрым фортрановским способом хранения данных. То есть экономнее некуда ).