# python не хватит оперативной памяти

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть ли в python механизм когда бросается исключение вроде std::bad_alloc(C++) если не получится поместить в оперативную память объект с диска ?

Comment: В 99 процентах случаев нет необходимости грузить большие объекты в память целиком. Какая у вас задача?

Comment: `OverflowError` есть, но я с ним работать не пробовал. Вообще, лучше избегать забивания памяти, как выше замечают

Comment: связанный вопрос [Размер списка в Python и объём оперативной памяти](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/467022/23044)

Comment: @andreymal: `OverflowError` это для арифметических операций и особых случаев: `2.0**2000`, `len(range(sys.maxsize+1))`. Для памяти MemoryError используется

Answer (score 2):

Есть `exception MemoryError`. Отлавливал когда писал даунлоадер файлов на облако. По какой-то причине не получилось сделать потоковую заливку (то-ли не осилил, то-ли сервер не поддерживал), поэтому приходилось помещать файл полностью в память.

Стоит отметить, что, если используешь 32-х битный питон, то такая ошибка будет райзиться всегда при попытке поместить в память что-то большее, чем 2 гб (вне зависимости сколько свободно)