# Как в питоне объявить список фиксированной длины, но не заполнять его?

Tags: python, массивы

К примеру строка

```
l=list(range(0,1000000000))
```

Вызове ошибку `MemoryError`, потому, что список в добавок к объявлению заполняется числами от 0 до 999999999.

Comment: Встречный вопрос - а зачем? Если вы больше раскажете о своей задаче, то вам могут подсказать другие решения... PS не стоит применять шаблоны С/С++ в Python

Comment: "Вот в с++ к примеру это делается легко", правда, результат немного не компилируется :) https://ideone.com/Or9N3C

Comment: Вы не можете создать список фиксированной длины, не заполнив его, ни в питоне, ни c++, ни в си, ни в любом другом языке. Список обязательно будет заполнен хоть чем-нибудь — например, нулями, null или None. И в любом из этих случаев вы рискуете получить MemoryError или его аналог в любом языке.

Comment: int arr[10]; тоже выделяет память для массива.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Список фиксированной длины - это скорее всего МАССИВ. Тогда так:

```
import numpy as np
MAXSIZE = 1000000
l = np.empty(MAXSIZE, dtype=np.int16)
```

только он будет заполнен "остаточным мусором", а не "Ничем".
Ничем вам показали в другом ответе )
Реализация массива в `numpy` намного более экономна по расходованию памяти, чем стандартный список, но не позволяет хранить объекты разных типов и добавлять или удалять элементы массива.
Кстати - если тип не указывать, то будет массив float

Comment: И всё равно на больших размерах будет MemoryError

Comment: @Александр ну для решения этой проблемы есть распределенное хранение данных на нескольких серверах, SPARK в конце концов.
Как известно - память ограничена физически, а натуральный ряд - нет. (:  Всегда найдется "слишком большой" размер массива

Comment: Удивительно, что автор принял и этот ответ тоже, ведь он не решает ни одной из проблем, обозначенных в вопросе (в котором, кстати, правок не было)

Comment: @andreymal -  я привел точный аналог `int arr[10];` для пайтона. Это то что хотел автор.

Comment: @КонстантинЛи, посмотрите встроенный модуль `array`. Я с ним не работал, но судя по описанию, делает он тоже самое.

Comment: @КонстантинЛи этот ответ также к MemoryError ведёт (может быть с небольшой задержкой. К примеру, у меня на телефоне `numpy.empty(10**9)` вызывает MemoryError

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71725/discussion-on-answer-by-vasyl-kolomiets------).

Answer (score 3):

Список в Питоне содержит ссылки на объекты. Нельзя создать список,  заданного размера, не заполнив его. Даже если все ссылки указывают на None:

```
L = [None] * 10**9
```

необходимо место под сами ссылки и рано или поздно вы получите MemoryError (мне не известны реализации Питона, где списки лениво создаются). См. [Размер списка в Python и объём оперативной памяти](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/467022/23044)

В качестве альтернативы, вы можете пустой список создать:

```
 L = []
```

и добавлять к нему элементы к нему по мере необходимости (`L.append({})`). Это не спасёт от MemoryError при достаточно большом количестве элементов.

Если вы хотите создать массив чисел, то для экономии памяти можно использовать [array модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), который может более компактное представление иметь. К примеру, что создать массив с миллиардом нулей:

```
import array

a = array.array('i', [0]) * 10**9
```

Это меньше памяти чем обычный список может занимать, но от MemoryError при достаточно больших размерах это не спасёт (также как и `numpy.empty(10**9)`). [Reserve memory for list in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/537086/4279)

Чтобы память не требовать, можно использовать ленивые последовательности, к примеру, в Питоне 3:

```
R = range(10**9)
```

Нужные элементы на лету могут создаваться. Большие размеры, такие как `range(10**21)`, не приводят к MemoryError в этом случае. Можно также свои классы создавать, к примеру, [размер GmtimeOverflowTable практически не ограничен.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32155104/4279)

Comment: [можно создать разреженную матрицу ...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/771155/211923)

Comment: @MaxU можно. sparse matrix относятся к специализированным классам типа, GmtimeOverflowTable — под конкретные задачи заточены (узкого назначения).

Answer (score 2):

```
import array


# i - integer https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html
# array<any> создать нельзя.
arr = array.array('i', range(1000000))
```

Answer (score 2):

Это можно сделать в Python (SciPy) используя [Sparse Matrices (разреженные матрицы)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).

Пример:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
```

создаем матрицу размерности `10^20 x 1` с 1000 ненулевых элементов:

```
row  = np.random.randint(10**10, size=10**3, dtype=np.int64)
col  = np.array([0] * 10**3)
data = np.random.randint(255, size=10**3)

coo = coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(10**20, 1))
```

результат:

```
In [29]: coo
Out[29]:
<100000000000000000000x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
        with 1000 stored elements in COOrdinate format>

In [30]: coo.shape
Out[30]: (100000000000000000000, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Например вот так:
`l = [None for i in range(1000000)]`

Comment: ']' в конце допишите. но в результате весь массив будет заполнен None

Comment: @AlexanderPushkarev, а что не так с None?

Comment: @Qwertiy с None все в порядке. Вопрос был об объявлении массива без инициализации элементов по типу int ar[10]. Jfs об этом позже написал.